# Is there a way to make selection form don't do anything when it's empty?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a selection form that submits to a database, but the problem is when the selection is not selected it will still submit the empty value to the database. Is there a way to ignore an empty selection form when it's empty when the submit button is clicked or when the page is reloaded?

Here is the code that I have been working on

```
<?php
//DB Connection
    $mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost','root','','mrbs');
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mrbs_users");

    //White board Current PIC
    $wb_current_pic = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mrbs_room_pic WHERE id='1'");
    $wb_search_pic = $wb_current_pic->fetch_assoc();
    $wb_pic = $wb_search_pic['name'];
?>

<form action="" method="post">  
        <div>
            White Board (Current PIC : <?php echo("$wb_pic");?>) 
            <div>
                <select name="white_board">
                    <?php
                        //echo "<option value=''>--set---</option>";
                        echo "<option value='' disabled selected>---set---</option>";
                        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                            $username = $rows['name'];
                            $user_email = $rows['email'];
                            echo "<option value='$user_email $username'>$username</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
    $wb_str = $_POST['white_board'];

    //string processing
    $wb_arr =  explode(" ",$wb_str);
    $wb_pic_email = $wb_arr['0'];
    $wb_pic_name = $wb_arr['1'];

    echo '<b>The PIC Adresses:</b>' .'<br>' .
    $wb_pic_email . "   " .$wb_pic_name .'<br>';

    //UPDATE DB
    $ex_query_wb = "UPDATE mrbs_room_pic SET name = '$wb_pic_name', email = '$wb_pic_email' WHERE id ='1'";
    mysqli_query($mysqli,$ex_query_wb);
?>
```

Based on the code, did I do something wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could put `required` in your select tag like this: `<select name="" required>`. Although people could just edit this, you would probably want to do some validation in your PHP code.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['white_board'])) { // do the stuff }`?

Comment: Why not check for anything before running that highly insecure query?

Comment: @Jeto hey it works, thanks

Comment: As @NicoHaase mentioned, your SQL queries are also very unsafe, as they're prone to SQL injection attacks. You should look into prepared statements.

Comment: @NicoHaase alright I'll try to do something to make it more secure, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your database query in a clause that checks that the strings are not empty, e.g.

```
// Use trim to remove any whitespace
if (trim($_POST['white_board']) === '') {
    // Tell the user to check their data
} else {    
    // Do query...
}
```

On a related note, I'd also suggest looking at sanitising and validating user input, and also consider using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli_query as it provides better protection against SQL injection. Your query is extremely vulnerable.